# Unable to create WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON object using QAndroidJniObject

Tags: android, c++, qt, qandroidjniobject

Here is my code, trying to create a [QAndroidJniObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html) to access [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) value.

So I do this:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    jint keepAliveField = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/view/WindowManager/LayoutParams","FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON");

    qDebug() << "keepAliveField=" << keepAliveField;
}
```

Any idea why this prints `keepAliveField=0`when I expect `keepAliveField=128`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is [WindowManager.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams), just replace the '.' with '$'

```
QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>(
            "android/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams", "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON");
```

Comment: A bit late ;-), but thank you, it fixes the issue!

Comment: Yes, just a bit 